# PHP changes do not register when executed

Tags: php, linux, apache, caching

I have a client with a dedicated `linux` server hosted by `godaddy` that runs PHP scripts. When I FTP in and make changes to the PHP files, the changes do not register when I execute the scripts through a browser (in other words, I hit the php page from chrome). It acts as though the old script is still in place and my changes were ignored.

I know that I have the right page, because if I rename the php file, the page breaks with 404 not found.

I know that `wordpress` has a nasty "feature" in which it caches php on the server and changes won't register without a reset - but my client assures me he is not running wordpress.

Godaddy has recommended setting `nocache=1` in querystrings, but that only works if my changes are registering, and they are not. Also, php's `include` and `include_once` don't seem to allow querystrings, so this whole approach seems problematic.

Any ideas how I can solve this? Or how can I detect the caching mechanism? My client and godaddy both seem clueless as to what is going on.

Comment: What about opcache or such features? Have you checked whether any caching technique is enabled in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

Check for disk space & INODE usage.

Even  Mod_security block cloud be the reason, check for the error logs

Also update the PHP VERSION to higher like 7.3 Which supports MYSQLI.

Comment: Mysqli was supported in php from at least 5.3